# React native elements list width is too narrow

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox, react-native-flexbox

I am using react-native-elements list from here: https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/API/lists/

When I render it with `flex: 1` it is very narrow.  When I render it with `width: 400` it is OK.

Here are the styles:

```
container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    half: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: '#FF0000'
    },
```

Here is the list code:

```
     <View style={styles.container}>
        { babyList.length === 0 ? null :
            <View style={styles.half}>
                <List containerStyle={{flex: 1}}>
                    <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                        Select Baby
                    </Text>
                    {babyList.map((baby, id) => {
                        return <ListItem key={"bbbtn" + id}
                                         onPress={ (event) => selectBaby(baby) } title={"Baby: " + baby.name}/>
                    })}
                </List>
            </View>
        }
      </View>
```

Here is what it looks like with the above code:

[image]

Here is what it looks like if I set the `containerStyle={{width: 400}}`

[image]

I thought the flex: 1 would make it the max width?  What do I need to do to make it take up the whole parent container?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because you overwrite the default `alignItems: 'stretch'` with `alignItems: 'center'`. Remove it from your stylesheet and all elements will be stretched to fill all available space.

Here's your code on Snack: https://snack.expo.io/r121RGj1G